# Alternative of boost::asio::executor_work_guard for older boost version (1.57)

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I need my `boost::asio::io_service` object prevent from exiting when there is no more work to do. The boost.asio library version that we are using is outdated and we are not yet allowed to upgrade. The 1.57 version we are using seems not to contain the `boost:asio::executor_work_guard` that could prevent the `io_service` object from exiting.
Are there any known alternatives to it in the old boost.asio version 1.57 (Linux)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In older versions you'd use a [`io_service::work`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service__work.html) object:

```
boost::asio::io_service io;
boost::asio::work work(io);
```

Note that to get reset() like functionality you'd wrap that in `boost::optional<>` or `std::unique_ptr<>`

This is actually still in the documentation for the 1.57.0 version in the same place(s) where you'd find executor_work_guard in newer versions, e.g. https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service.html#boost_asio.reference.io_service.stopping_the_io_service_from_running_out_of_work